# ¿Cómo puedo poner una validación para que solo lea valores enteros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Para mi código requiero que se haga una validación, que la variable promedio lea solo números enteros y si el usuario coloca números que no sean enteros que despliegue un mensaje de error. ¿Qué código puedo poner para que me haga esta validación?
Este es todo mi código:

```
 else:
              
                nombre=     mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el nombre del alumno: ")
                ap_paterno= mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el apellido paterno del alumno: ")
                ap_materno= mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el apellido materno del alumno: ")
                carrera=    mu.pide_cadena(3,3,"Escribe la carrera del alumno: ")
                promedio=   mu.pide_entero(0,100,"Escribe el promedio en enterp del alumno: ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias creear una funcion que lea datos enteros y lance una exepcion si no recibe un dato del tipo que quieras.

```py
def lee_entero():
    """ Solicita un valor entero y lo devuelve.
        Mientras el valor ingresado no sea entero, vuelve a solicitarlo. """
    while True:
        valor = raw_input("Ingrese un número entero: ")
        try:
            valor = int(valor)
            return valor
        except ValueError:
            print "ATENCIÓN: Debe ingresar un número entero."
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya quedó 